# TFS 2017 - aspnet_regiis.exe On release definition?

Tags: asp.net, batch-file, tfs

I have a batch script step that runs at the end of my web deploy the script encrypts a connection string in web.config using aspnet_regiis.exe, In the logs it looks like it went fine but it doesnt acctually encrypt the connectionString, when i run the batch locally on my remote machine it works. Is there a way to do through Release definition or the user has to run the batch locally every time?

here is the code.

```
start C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -pe "connectionStrings" -app "/" -site "2"
echo Encryption Successfull!
pause
```

Comment: Did you get any error or prompting info？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First suggest you using your build service account RDP to the remote machine and run the batch script. Double check if you are missing any permission for the account.

Since , the logs it looks like it went fine but it doesn't actually encrypt the connectionString. Also try to do some test below to perform it:

- Have you compared the transformed web.config file that is deployed to
  server to the original encrypted config file? Test with both files on
  server.
- Try unencrypting the config file on server and see if you get the
  correct connection strings back.

Comment: Just found a solution.It was rights error, Agent running under network services, NetworkServices dont have the rights. I change the agent to run under administrator and it works that not ideal but works. How can i set Administrator rights for NetworkServices?

Comment: If i change NetworkServices right to administrator it only works for the webpage deployed which is not good to me,Everytime a new website is deployed NetworkServices rights are back to default.

Comment: @WojtekT If so, did you have to run the agent as a service mode? Could you give a try with running the release with  one build agent configured as Interactive mode instead of service. This could give the account enough permission,which may do the trick. https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/agents/agents#account